# how to show actual price of simple products in configurable product view page select box

Tags: magento-1.9

Currently it shows

[image]

I want the actual price and not the price Difference with + sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. List item

This is performed by javascript. You need to modify the method getOptionLabel in js/varien/configurable.js

find below code in js:

```
getOptionLabel: function(option, price){
var price = parseFloat(price);
```

replace with this:

```
getOptionLabel: function(option, price){
var basePrice = parseFloat(this.config.basePrice);
var absoluteDifference = parseFloat(option.price);
var absoluteFinalPrice = basePrice + absoluteDifference;
// var price = parseFloat(price);
var price = absoluteFinalPrice; }
```

For remove + and - sign comment below code:

```
 formatPrice: function(price, showSign){
    var str = '';
    price = parseFloat(price);
    /*if(showSign){
        if(price<0){
            str+= '-';
            price = -price;
        }
        else{
            str+= '+';
        }
    }*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for me? Website:https://www.mirror-engraving.com/laser-engraved-mirror-etched-picture

Configurable field is: Size

Please have a look at my code below if I made a mistake here:

```
    getOptionLabel: function(option, price){
    var basePrice = parseFloat(this.config.basePrice);
    var absoluteDifference = parseFloat(option.price);
    var absoluteFinalPrice = basePrice + absoluteDifference;
    // var price = parseFloat(price);
    var price = absoluteFinalPrice; }

    if (this.taxConfig.includeTax) {
        var tax = price / (100 + this.taxConfig.defaultTax) * this.taxConfig.defaultTax;
        var excl = price - tax;
        var incl = excl*(1+(this.taxConfig.currentTax/100));
    } else {
        var tax = price * (this.taxConfig.currentTax / 100);
        var excl = price;
        var incl = excl + tax;
    }

    if (this.taxConfig.showIncludeTax || this.taxConfig.showBothPrices) {
        price = incl;
    } else {
        price = excl;
    }

    var str = option.label;
    if(price){
        if (this.taxConfig.showBothPrices) {
            str+= ' ' + this.formatPrice(excl, true) + ' (' + this.formatPrice(price, true) + ' ' + this.taxConfig.inclTaxTitle + ')';
        } else {
            str+= ' ' + this.formatPrice(price, true);
        }
    }
    return str;
},

formatPrice: function(price, showSign){
    var str = '';
    price = parseFloat(price);
    /*if(showSign){
        if(price<0){
            str+= '-';
            price = -price;
        }
        else{
            str+= '+';
        }
    }*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should delete ";" in

```
var price = absoluteFinalPrice; }
```

It's not needed there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above for part 1 needs the last character of } removed to work ie -

```
getOptionLabel: function(option, price){
var basePrice = parseFloat(this.config.basePrice);
var absoluteDifference = parseFloat(option.price);
var absoluteFinalPrice = basePrice + absoluteDifference;
// var price = parseFloat(price);
var price = absoluteFinalPrice;
```